# GeoCorder: Cannot pass LatLng in getFromLocation()

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-geocoder

Now I'm trying to get a location's country name but I cannot pass `LatLng` in `getFromLocation()`.
How can I fix this?

```
public void checkCountry(LatLng location) {
     Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefaut());
     List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.logtitude, 1); //error here
     String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
```

The error says

> Unhandled Exception: java.IO.Exception
>
> getFromLocation() cannot be applied to:
> latitude double location.latitude
> longtitude double location.longtitude

What am I wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just handle the exception. either throw it or catch it.

```
public void checkCountry(LatLng location) {
    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefaut());
    List<Address> addresses=new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        addresses=  gcd.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1); //error here
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String country;
    if(addresses!=null)if(addresses.size()!=0) country= addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
}
```